# How can I remove URLs from Google search that contain my product name?

Tags: google, url, search-results

I'm working for a company, and while searching for their name in Google, the results returned contain links with their product name in them that I want to be removed.

Is there any way Google can help me solve this, or can this only be resolved by talking with the website's managers? What if they don't agree?

Comment: You cannot remove links to your site short of asking the site owner to remove them. This is not always easy. What is it about these sites/links that you find objectionable??

Comment: Well, the comapnie that I'm working for doesnt want those links in the middle of ours in the search engine, because it can confuse the client.

Comment: Oh. Well, not to be cruel, that is too bad. You will have no control over this. Search engines return results based upon complex algorithms and you cannot control how they return search results. You can create content that out performs these pages of course, however, do know that search engines will return only a small number of results per page for your site in any search. If these are truly objectionable, such as slanderous, then you can take the legal route. However, people have the right to create whatever content they want (generally) and have it appear in search.

Comment: Got the message... Will try to do what I can! The legal part seems to last a lot of time and it might even not work. Thank you for the help provided!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the links in question are doing something illegal in connection with the product name, you can try to file a DMCA (Digital Millennium Copyright Act) report against the people who manage the URLs the links point to and/or file a lawsuit against them. Then again, it depends on how illegal the act is to begin with.

If you did invent the product name, it would be extremely helpful if you had a set of laws surrounding third-party usage of the product name or anything else related to the product so that you have something to back you up should someone use your product name in an illegal way.

I personally would find it silly if for example, you were selling a product and you wanted to remove the blog URL (that is listed before yours) that talks about how wonderful the same product is along with providing a link to your site. It's like asking to burn bridges.

If you do want to rank on top of the list, you should follow Google's Webmaster guidelines and write quality content.

Other than that, good luck.